# In Geany IDE: How to Find and delete entire line

Tags: regex, geany

In the Geany IDE, how can I find all lines in a .css file starting with `-moz-border-radius` using regex and delete the entire line without leaving a blank line?

Answer (score 3):

The following works in Geany 1.36 on Debian Linux...

**In the Search and Replace dialog...**

- Check `Use regular expressions`
- Check `Use multi-line matching`
- Enter the following in the `Search for` field...

  `^\s*-moz-border-radius.*$\n`
- Leave the `Replace with` field empty.

**Regular Expression Explanation**

- `^` Start at beginning of line
- `\s*` Zero or more whitespaces
- `-moz-border-radius` The text to search for
- `.*` Zero or more of any characters
- `$` End of the line
- `\n` Include the newline. This is the non-standard part. Apparently Geany recognizes the newline escape sequence following a regular-expression End-Of-Line($).